# k specific prime factors guess and related prime guess

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-ideals, prime-gaps

there is no more than one group
of continuous composite sequence
of length k composed of only k different specific prime factors.
for example  2 3 5[8 9 10]just only one group. I have prove that k prime factors can form
f(n) sequence k numbers

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I agree with @StefanWaldmann:  not only is there no obvious question, it's not even clear what your statement is.  (Probably 'continuous' means 'consecutive', but, for example, are $k$ and $n$ in "$f(n)$ sequence $k$ numbers" the same thing?)