# Do $k$ specific prime factors uniquely determine the continuous composite sequence of length $k$?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, prime-ideals, prime-gaps, prime-constellations

猜想:不存在两个长度为k且一共含有k个不同素因子的连续合数序列的素因子集合相等。例如
24 25 26 27 (2 3 5 13)

其余长度为4的连续合数序列要么素因子个数大于4  要么素因子集合不等于{2 3 5 13}  这个连续合数猜想的重大特定情况下的猜想。难度可与哥德巴赫猜想匹敌，非天才误入。再比如2 3 5 唯一决定了8 9 10 除此之外再无其他。总之经过计算机验证没有找到反例。

---

Attempt at translation of the main aspects:

Let $S$ be a set of positive integers. Denote by
$$ P(S) := \{ p: p \text{ is a prime factor of some } s\in S\} $$
Example: $P(\{24,25,26,27\}) = \{2,3,5,13\}$.

> **Conjecture**: if $S_1, S_2$ are two sets of $k$ *consecutive* composite positive integers, such that $P(S_1) = P(S_2)$ and $|P(S_1)| = k$, then $S_1= S_2$.

Computer searches have not yielded counterexamples.

Comment: Welcome to an international Q&A site, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour). Sorry, but this site has [English-only policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/241919). Consider [edit]ing and translating to English as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong: you can edit the question, maybe add the English translation to it?

Comment: Actually, this appears to be an attempt to clarify the OP's previous question https://mathoverflow.net/q/391982/3948 which **was** posted in English but was unfortunately rather unclear.

Comment: Isn't $S_1 = \{2,3\}$ and $S_2 = \{8,9\}$ a counterexample?

Comment: here are some person can not understand what i see.

Comment: Interesting (?): the sets, for which $|P(S)|=|S|$, seems to be restricted to small integers. The example the OP gives seems to be the set with the highest numbers for $k=4$.

Comment: 4 5 6 7 contain prime  pass

Comment: all  numbers is not prime     can you understand

Comment: I edited the "composite" condition into the question. (I only took a quick glance when translating and missed the assumption that the numbers are composite.) @光子精灵S precisely the problem is that if you pose the question in Chinese most people cannot understand it. You are certainly welcome to look over my attempt to translate your question and see if there are any remaining omissions.

Comment: I assume you also want $k > 1$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen my mistake in translation. I failed to notice that the OP qualified the sequence as only of composite numbers.

Comment: @JohannesTrost: my bad in translation; see previous comment.

Comment: thanks for your edit after